# Swagger API Documentation in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, api-doc

I am facing the problem in setting up Swagger. How can I implement Swagger to in my node-express project to write API Doc for existing APIs?
I have looked swagger, swagger-ui, and swagger-ui-dist npm packages. But not getting the desired output. 
I want to use Swagger UI but getting counfused in the confugurations. Can anybody tell me the step by step guide for the configuration?
Need help.

Comment: You might be looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-node-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After basic installation:

Here is a STEP-BY-STEP guide.

- [**Adding Swagger To Existing Node.js Project**](https://blog.cloudboost.io/adding-swagger-to-existing-node-js-project-92a6624b855b)
- [**Using Swagger UI with any codebase**](https://yanhan.github.io/posts/2017-11-26-using-swagger-ui-with-any-codebase.html)

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks man. Although it doesn't completely solve my problem but gave hint to me :)
Its now been solved.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Yeah sure buddy !

Answer (score 0):

A good option for beginners is to install the Swagger NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger and follow the instructions.

Overview:

```
// install
npm install -g swagger

// create a new project
swagger project create hello-world

// edit your API using the Swagger UI
swagger project edit
```

Then follow the rest of the instructions on how to code up your controllers.

Comment: I have implemented this. But I want to use Swagger UI

Comment: `swagger project edit` will give you access to the Swagger UI (launches it in a browser) or is this not what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Best npm package is swagger-autogen, which simplifies the process of generating Swagger documentation for your API.

## swagger-autogen

```bash
$ npm i swagger-autogen
```

npm [swagger-autogen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-autogen).

For more details and examples, you can visit the  [swagger-autogen GitHub Repository](https://github.com/davibaltar/example-swagger-autogen-with-router).

[More info](https://swagger-autogen.github.io/docs)